# Can't uninstall sass gem to use newer version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass

I can't seem to uninstall an old version of sass
I've done

```
sudo gem uninstall sass
```

as well as

```
sudo gem uninstall sass --version 3.2.14
```

When I try to do

```
sudo gem update sass
```

It says there are no updates.

What's the best way from here to force usage of the latest gem?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the latest update? Have you tried `sass -v` ?

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't tried taking sudo out. That did the trick.